# Fechar página ao imprimir

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte situação: Ao confirmar a abertura de um chamado, na confirmação direciona para a página de impressão. Ao carregar, ela já exibe a opção de imprimir, dessa forma:

```
<body onload="window.print();">
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como a janela voltar para a página anterior ao iniciar a impressão. Por exemplo, voltar ao `index.php` após fechar a janela de impressão.
Obrigado

Comment: Mas quando você clica em cancelar ou fechar depois de imprimir ela não volta? Não entendi.

Comment: Ele abre a janela de impressão, quando seleciono a impressora e imprimo ele fecha a janela, exatamente como eu precisava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ficar registrado, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
<body onload="ClosePrint()">
```

Função:

```
function ClosePrint() {
      setTimeout(function () { window.print(); }, 500);
      window.onfocus = function () { setTimeout(function () { window.close(); }, 500); }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta acrescentar os seguintes códigos:

```
<script>
    window.print();
    window.addEventListener("afterprint", function(event) { window.close(); });
    window.onafterprint();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Para qualquer um tropeçar em cima deste resposta do Google, deixe-me tentar esclarecer as coisas:

Como Ajay apontou, há dois eventos que são disparados para impressão, mas eles não são bem suportado; na medida em que eu li, eles só são suportados no (6+) browsers Internet Explorer e Firefox. Esses eventos são window.onbeforeprint e window.onafterprint, que (como seria de esperar) será acionado antes e depois do trabalho de impressão.

No entanto, como apontado na ligação de Joe ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920784/578667 ), isso não é exatamente como ele é implementado em todos os casos. Na maioria dos casos, ambos os eventos disparar antes do diálogo; em outros, a execução do script pode ser interrompida durante o diálogo de impressão, para que ambos os eventos podem disparar ao mesmo tempo (após o diálogo foi concluído).

Para mais informações (e suporte ao navegador) para estes dois eventos:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeprint

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onafterprint

A resposta curta: se você está esperando para interferir com o fluxo de impressão, não o fazem. Se você está esperando para acionar o código após a impressão, não vai funcionar como você está querendo; esperar o apoio navegador pobres, e tentar degradar normalmente.

Fonte : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138939/how-to-trigger-javascript-on-print-event

Comment: Além da tradução ruim, não concordo com sua resposta. Se você verificar aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes o método que usei funciona EM QUALQUER NAVEGADOR. Da forma que eu precisava, imprimir e fechar, funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Outra, em nenhum momento usei os métodos window.onbeforeprint e window.onafterprint. Não sei porque dessa resposta, se não tem nada a ver com a solução.

Comment: Ok, uma solução com setTimeout funciona. Será que é a melhor forma ? kkkkkkkkkkk